# I have an idea!/ I've just got an idea(expression)

Tags: phrase-usage, expressions

Let's say you and your colleagues are figuring out how to save time doing your daily work. And then you suddenly **come up with an idea**, how do you *say* this if it happened **abruptly**?

> Guys, I have an idea!

Or

> Guys, I've just got an idea!

Or

> Guys, An idea just popped into my head!

which is the correct expression here?
P.S: The register is casual conversation

Comment: Have you thought this through? It's not always appropriate to address your audience as "Guys", so *that's* a difference. Including "just" explicitly emphasises "recency" (or feasibly, "triviality", but I doubt that would be intended). And to speak of anything "popping into your head" is obviously a very relaxed informal idiomatic usage. Your choice depends what context you're speaking in, and what kind of impression you want to give.

Comment: In casual conversation, this will definitely work: **Hey, I got an idea.**

Comment: @MichaelRybkin, nice! that's what I've been looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In casual conversation, you can say

> **I've got an idea!**

you can also say

> **Aha!**

or

> **I've got it!**